# Selecting the columns which are not null from a tuple

Tags: sql, null

Imagine if we have a table:

```
| col1 | val1 | val2 | val3 | val4 | val5 |
-------------------------------------------
| A    |   1  | null | null | null |   1  |
| B    | null |   1  | null |   1  | null |
| C    |    1 | null |   1  | null | null |
```

and can i write an SQL query to give me a the following result, where i can get the columns which are not null :

```
| col1 | val1 | val5 |
----------------------
| A    |   1  |   1  |
```

rather than using a separate function to do the same?

Comment: You sure can: `select col1, val1, val5 from t where col1 = 'A'`. Seriously, what are the rules that are applied to the table to get the result? Why are rows `B` and `C` not returned?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You don't state RDBMS but it will likely require a query to determine the columns that contain `NOT NULL` then a separate dynamic SQL query to return the actual result.

Comment: I'd just `SELECT col1, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 FROM Table` and worry about DBNull code-side.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: thnx for the reply, here i want to select only the column which are not null, can do the same with a simple PLSQL func, but wanted to knw whether there is a way to do it from the SQL query itself. And yes, the query will be smthng lyk " SELECT <the part in need> FROM table t WHERE t.col1 = 'A'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not specify what RDBMS you are using but you can *unpivot* the data to return the data that contains non-null values.  If you do not have an `UNPIVOT` function then you can use a `UNION ALL`:

```
select col1, 'val1' col, val1
from yourtable
where val1 is not null
union all
select col1, 'val2' col, val2
from yourtable
where val2 is not null
union all
select col1, 'val3' col, val3
from yourtable
where val3 is not null
union all
select col1, 'val4' col, val4
from yourtable
where val4 is not null
union all
select col1, 'val5' col, val5
from yourtable
where val5 is not null
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14c81/4).

If you have an RDBMS with an unpivot function then the query will be similar to this:

```
select col1, col, value
from yourtable
unpivot
(
  value
  for col in (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5)
) unpiv;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/14c81/1).  The data is returned as rows instead of the separate columns but the result is:

```
| COL1 |  COL | VALUE |
-----------------------
|    A | val1 |     1 |
|    A | val5 |     1 |
|    B | val2 |     1 |
|    B | val4 |     1 |
|    C | val1 |     1 |
|    C | val3 |     1 |
```

Comment: works like a charm!!! thanx alot!! :D
not totally wt i expected but turns out this is easy for my purpose!!

Answer (score 2):

The answer is "no", not in standard SQL.  The `select` statement specifies the specific columns that are returned.  You cannot vary the number of columns.

One option is to switch to "dynamic" SQL, where you create the query as a character string and then execute that.  The methods for this are highly database dependent.

Another alternative would be to group all the values into a single column, using something like `listagg` (your comment suggests you are using Oracle).

If you want the non-NULL column names as well, you can do this with `listagg` and a giant `case` statement.  Alternatively, you could unpivot the data to get name-value pairs and then reaggregate using `listagg`.